# jQuery `find(selector)`: is there a way to reference each matched element?

Tags: jquery, reference, find, element

I am using `find(sel)` to change css properties of all elements matched by `sel`: if the element has a `position` set, then it should get that `position`, otherwise it should get `relative`.

```
$("#mydiv").find("form").css({ "z-index": 2, "position": jQuery(this).css("position") || "relative", "background-color": "green" })
```

does not work.. best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Aren't they all going to be `static` by default? They'll have a position value, so maybe you should check if it's static or not.

Comment: yep, `return (jQuery(this).css("position") != "static") ? jQuery(this).css("position") : "relative"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variant of [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value)

```
$("#mydiv").find("form").css({
    "z-index": 2,
    "position": function(){
        return jQuery(this).css("position") || "relative"
    },
    "background-color": "green"
})
```